# Autoplay audio playlist SoundManager2 bar-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

** EDITED **

See Jon Black's answer below as the correct solution...

I am trying to use SoundManager2 HTML5 Audio Player on a website for a client, however the client is insisting that the .mp3 playlist **auto-play** starting with track 1 and cycling through the rest of the tracks.

The original script (soundmanager2.js on the site) has an autoPlay: false option, but changing this to true does nothing.

Here is a link to a demo website I've created making use of SoundManager2's bar-ui (which is the style the client wants to use) and a script to autoplay an .mp3 track in the background: [website with working demo](http://4nchor.com/SO2/)

As you can see (and hear), the background audio auto-plays nicely, but NOT through the sound bar, as expected. If you click Play or click on a playlist item in the track menu, the newly clicked audio simply plays OVER the background audio, which is not desired. I need the playlist audi to autoplay with the ability to play, pause and select different tracks through the sound bar itself.

[Here is the link to original SoundManager2 project website for further info](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/).

I am hoping someone can tell me how to create a function or provide a script that will allow the playlist to play THROUGH the audio player UI automatically on page load.

I have done a TON of searching and have tried writing and piecing together scripts, but just cannot seem to get this working! So, I turn to the GENIUSES on SO.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Try adding 'autoPlay: true,' to line 794 of bar-ui.js.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson - Apologies, but the entire code IS the problem... I cannot seem to get autoPlay:true to play nicely and work. I have tried setting the function(s) provided in the documentation, and adding autoPlay:true in numerous places, but to no avail.

Comment: @jmiraglia tried adding 'autoPlay: true,' to line 794 of bar-ui.js, still no-go... thanks for the suggestion, though. I really appreciate the assistance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a quick and easy way to take care of your dilemma.  You just have to add this simple code after the `init()` call on or around `line 1378` of `bar-ui.js`.

```
    soundObject = makeSound(playlistController.getURL());
    soundObject.togglePause();
```

After `init()` sets the player up, you just need to queue up the first sound on the playlist(with `makeSound(playlistController.getURL()`) and then play(with  `togglePause()`).

Comment: I cannot upvote (too new to the site, apparently, but this worked PERFECTLY and has been marked as the correct solution! Thank you SO much for your time and expertise Jon Black & everyone who shared answers.

Answer (score 2):

The solution above is not working for me.
It changes the button state but the file doesn't play. I get this underlined error in  chrome console

```
sound0: play(): Loading - attempting to play...
bar-ui.js:125 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

And here it shows autoPlay is true.

```
Object {url: "http://freshly-ground.com/data/audio/sm2/SonReal%20-%20LA%20%28Prod%20Chin%20Injetti%29.mp3", volume: 100, autoLoad: false, autoPlay: true, from: null…}
```

Comment: Then what is solution ??

Answer (score 0):

To be clear about Jon's solution:
add the two lines he mentions to bar-ui.js and insert in your soundManager.setup

```
onready: function() {
makeSound(playlistController.getURL());
togglePause();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello John V, I am not sure where you are saying to add the code you provided, but I only did what Jon Black suggested and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error of Oj Obasi when I tried the solution of Jon Black, so instead of adding those two lines immediately after the init() call I added them after the declaration of exports and it worked well.
Here is the edit I made:

```js
init(); // the init call

    exports = {
      // Per-instance events: window.sm2BarPlayers[0].on = { ... } etc. See global players.on example above for reference.
      on: null,
      actions: actions,
      dom: dom,
      playlistController: playlistController
    };
    soundObject = makeSound(playlistController.getURL()); // these two lines make it autoplays the playlist from beginning
    soundObject.togglePause(); // these two lines make it autoplays the playlist from beginning
    return exports;
```

Comment: it would be nice if you include a part of code in your post which makes it independent from other answers - [from Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11995708)

Comment: Done. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To autoplay a single file using the SM2 player, (not a playlist) include the following on page load:

```
sm2BarPlayers[0].actions.play();
```